# How to make processing faster when reading CSV and JSON files in java?

Tags: java, json, csv

So I've made a running program in java that compares an existing library to csv files. My Problem is that the CSVs have a total of 105641 lines that I need to go through for each object in my library.

The program works like this:

```
Read all CSVs
Put in CSVList
Get all Objects in Library(JSON)
Loop each Objects
   Loop CSVList
      Compare Objects and CSV
          Display any mismatch
```

**Library structure:**

```
{
    "Library1": [{
            "id": 0,
            "Group": "Group_Name",
            "name": "Unique_Name_in_Group",
            "CHAIN1": {
                "location": ["location1", "location2", "location3", "location4"],
                "role": [["Role1"], ["Role2"], ["Role3"], ["Role4"], ["Role5"], ["Role6"]]
            },
            "CHAIN2": {
                "location": ["location1", "location2", "location3"],
                "role": [["Role1"], ["Role2"], ["Role3"], ["Role4"], ["Role5"], ["Role6"], ["Role7"], ["Role8"]]
            },
            "CHAIN3": {
                "SUBCHAIN": ["Subchain1", "Subchain2", "Subchain3", "Subchain4"],
                "location": ["location1", "location2", "location3", "location4"],
                "role": [["Role1"], ["Role2"], ["Role3"], ["Role4"], ["Role5"], ["Role6"]]
            }
        },
        .
        .
        .

}
```

**My CSV:**

- **Structure(5 Columns):** [Group_Name][Name][Location][Role]
- **Sorting:** A-Z From Left-Right
- 1 CSV = 1 Chain/Subchain
- CHAIN1..n is the name of the CSVs

Comment: You could profile the code to see what's taking most of the time. From the information you've given us there's nothing we can help you with (especially since there's no code).

Comment: Problem statement is still not clear like this, what are you trying to exactly compare in JSONObject with CSV files, how many files are there  etc. Please

Comment: At a first glance the nested loop looks as a starting point for some performance tweaking to me as it leads to O(M*N) Can you tell anything about the nature of "Objects" and "CSVList". What does "Display any mismatch" mean? Is order of elements in any of those collections relevant?